# Como usar metodos de varias clases en otra clase

Tags: java, eclipse

tengo un proyecto donde he creado 3 clases(Persona, jugador y ruleta). Y ahora me dispongo a crear mi 4 clase que es el main, es una clase donde quiero usar los métodos creados en las 3 clases. La cosa es que las 4 clases están en el mismo paquete, pero no se como puedo utilizar los métodos de las 3 clases en una(sin tener que usar herencia). He estado buscando y no se que hacer, os dejo aquí una foto de la estructura del paquete y sus clases.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código va como texto por favor

Comment: Quieres usar los métodos de las demás clases sin usar sus instancias?

Comment: Si,quiero usar los metodos de clases sin usar sus instancias y usandolas tambien pero sin usar herencia.